# Retrieving a Value from a wp-database

Tags: plugins, database, forms, sql

why my sql statement is not returning any value.. is this wrong?

```
<?php

        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_frm_item_metas"));
        foreach ($result as $item){
            $eventname= $result->meta_value;
        }

        ?>

        <h2><?php echo $eventname;?></h2>
```

What I'm doing is, I'm displaying the data stored in database using formidable form.. (not pro).. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the `$result` NULL, false or an empty array? Are you sure wp_frm_item_metas is a valid database name to be asking`$wpdb` of? Try echoing out `$wpdb->wp_frm_item_metas` and see what it gives you, check that the table is in the database and is called that way. Turn on error output for both $wpdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe for your foreach function should be like below:

```
foreach ($result as $item){
            $eventname= $item->meta_value;
        }
```

Comment: This answer was accepted but strikes me as wrong. `$eventname` is going to be only the last item in `$result` whether the query returns 1 or 100 elements.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

1. Unless you, or a plugin, has added `wp_frm_item_metas` to `$wpdb`,
   `$wpdb` has not idea what `$wpdb->wp_frm_item_metas` is. You will
   get an "Undefined Property" error, and your query won't work.

   You can't just use `$wpdb->` plus any table name. That won't work.
   You have to add the property to `$wpdb`, which [isn't that hard to
   do](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/116641/edit).
2. Your `foreach` is wrong. You are Looping over `$results` but at each
   iteration you need to be accessing `$item`, not `$result`. Like so:

   ```
   foreach ($result as $item){
     echo $item->meta_value;
   }
   ```
3. However, your query contains no limiting login-- no `WHERE` clause--
   so it will return every row in the `wp_frm_item_metas` table. So,
   either you need this... 
       foreach ($result as $item){
         $eventname[] = $item->meta_value;
       } ..., which doesn't make sense given your attempt to `echo $eventname;`
4. Or both your query and your choice of `$wpdb` method is wrong. It
   looks to me like you need something closer to this:

   ```
   $eventname = $wpdb->get_var(
     $wpdb->prepare(
       "SELECT meta_value* FROM $wpdb->wp_frm_item_metas WHERE something = %s",
       'something'
     )
   );
   ```

   You can now `echo $eventname` without the bother of the loop.
5. Notice how I altered the `prepare` method call. `$wpdb->prepare`
   ***must have*** two arguments. Your code would have failed at that point as well.

For reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

And please [enable debugging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983) while you work. You would have spotted much of this had you followed that simple rule.

Answer (score -1):

You got an error on your code, the **$eventname** should contain **$item->meta_value**

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/31580/21376), though flawed in its own way, does point out why `$eventname` does not contain `$item->meta_value`.

Answer (score -1):

ok I got it thanks a lot..

now I tried to display the output in a proper way like this..
Column 1 – Event name (with clickable link that when clicked goes to a page that shows the single event on a page with details)
Column 2 – Date of event 
Column 3 – City,State.(place)

here is my code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_frm_item_metas where field_id IN (8,13, 12, 11 )";
                    $result = @mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
                    ?><table border="1" colspan="3">
                    <th>Event</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Venue<?
                    $i=1;
                    while($i <= 1)
                    { echo "<tr>";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){



                            if($row['field_id'] == 8){
                                    $title = $row['meta_value'];

                            }

                            else if($row['field_id'] == 13){
                                    $link = $row['meta_value'];
                            echo "<td><a href=$link target=_blank> $title </a></td>";

                            }

                            else if($row['field_id'] == 12){
                                    $date=$row['meta_value'];
                                    echo "<td>$date</td>";
                            }



                            else {
                                    $place=$row['meta_value'];

                                    echo "<td>$place</td>";
                            }



                            $i++;


                    }      



                    echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            ?>
                            </table>
```

but the output is really confusing.. in the first column is the venue..
the second is correct the date.. and the third is the title..
Why the display is like that?

Here's the structure of the database:

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to be an "Answer" but another question or perhaps an edit to the original question. Please do not abuse the "Answer" box by posting further questions. An "Answer" should be a solution to the problem posted in the question.

Comment: Also, why did you start with a question that uses Core functions and methods and end up using no Core functions at all?