# Where do I get "Bug Information" to add to a question?

Tags: support

I have exactly the same issue as [this closed question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/86946/cant-click-on-widgets-and-upload-media-anymore) and want to resolve it.  In the comment section it asks the OP to add "Bug Information".

Where do I get bug information from so I can add it to my question on this stack?

I am new to WordPress (if thats not obvious) and I'm using [WordPress 3.5.1](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/3.5-branch) and the [Weaver 2](http://weavertheme.com/) theme

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to your site's `wp-config.php`. That will cause errors, warnings, and notices (non-fatal warnings) to print to the screen. Those are the "debug information" so frequently requested.

It is not advisable to have this enabled on a production (publicly accessible) server but if you have to have the debugging information then you have to have to have it.

You can also add `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` and the debugging information will be written to a file named `/wp-content/debug.log`.

You can then add `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` to prevent errors from printing to the screen as you can read them from the debug file.

So, in your `wp-config.php` you'd have:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Your server itself may also keep log file. The location and names of these files vary by OS. On Debian Squeeze, Apache's log is by at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. On CentOS 6 it is at `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. Those have much the same information, but you may not have direct access to them depending on your host and hosting type-- shared, vpn, etc. The database server may also keep logs.