# wp-cron: freeze at "now"

Tags: wp-cron

sorry for the silly question. Briefly I have a wp (v. 3.5.1) blog using a heavily modified (by myself) theme. Everything works fine except for wp-cron. Listed jobs appears in (for instance) crontrol and time passes until they come to "now" (which means that the job should start). Anyway nothing happens: scheduled post freeze at "now", my custom functions freeze at "now" and so on. Everything works if I manually run it (so no code problems). I tried to disable wp-cron (with
`define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` and set up a custom wp-cron (with its crontab entry) but without success. Finally I get the following error message:

> There was a problem spawning a call to the WP-Cron system on your site. This means WP-Cron jobs on your site may not work. The problem was:
>   connect() timed out!

which disappear if I set `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON',true);`.

Thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: Try [logging the debug information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376) and see if you get anything useful.

Comment: Also: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/problems-with-scheduler though that issue was solved with `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON',true);` and it seems that yours isn't.

Comment: Thans s_ha_dum: debug infos were already setted (I have a lot of Notices but no Warning). Anyway /wp-content/debug.log doesn't exist... Ah, little update: menus links to private pages do not work anymore (at a sudden!) when a common user is logged in (they keep working fine for admin). Very strange! I worked all day long without this issue... :(

Comment: Just for the record: I solved the "not found" issue uninstalling "WP-Cron Control" (???) which was my last plugin installed...

Comment: Thanks for the replies @s_ha_dum.
I also put a .htaccess, because I read that it can maybe a problem related to it (I didn't have an .htaccess). This is the code I put in it:
`
<Files "wp-cron.php">
Allow from All
Satisfy Any
</Files>
`
But no success again...  :(

Answer (score 1):

Mmmh, some progress: I'm able to activate wp-cron by browser (not really clear, because I have a white screen...): anyway, if I browse wp-cron, jobs are correctly executed and rescheduled... Now I have to understand why crontab do not work...