# Fetch a single row from a custom table for to a given ID

Tags: database, mysql

When I want to get a single row from a custom table of my WordPress database by providing a username through a function call, it does not work. When I mention the username in the `where` clause of the query, however, it works. Why is that?

I am using the following code:

```
function gettingonly($phl) {

    global $wpdb;
    $mylink = $wpdb->get_row("
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->wp_philosophy_philosopher
    WHERE philosopher=%s",
        $phl
    );
    if ($mylink) {
        print "<input type='text' value='" . $mylink->philosopher . "'>
        <input type='text' value='" . $mylink->about . "'>";
    }
}
```

Is this the right method to fetch a row by providing the value through the PHP function?

Answer (score 1):

`$wpdb->wp_philosophy_philosopher` won't work here because it has not been defined. `$wpdb->table_name` works only with default tables.

You can create your own using:

```
$wpdb->philosophy_philosopher = $wpdb->prefix . "philosophy_philosopher";
```

Note that the `wp_` is just the table prefix and has been omitted here because different installations can have different prefixes and that your code stop to work if you change your table prefix.

You can update your code to:

```
function gettingonly($phl) {

  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->philosophy_philosopher = $wpdb->prefix . "philosophy_philosopher"; 
  $mylink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->philosophy_philosopher WHERE philosopher=%s",$phl);
  #the rest of your code
}
```

Also, learn to [prepare your statements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function gettingonly( $phl ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_philosophy_philosopher WHERE philosopher="."'".$phl."'" );

    if( $mylink ){
        print "<input type='text' value='" . $mylink->philosopher . "'>
        <input type='text' value='" . $mylink->about . "'>";
    }
}
```

For more information read [WPDB WordPress Codex Entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with existing code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your query through `$wpdb->prepare`. As is, you are sending a literal `SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_philosophy_philosopher WHERE philosopher=%s` as a query. (The `$phl` drops off completely.) That will trigger a MySQL error.

```
$mylink = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}philosophy_philosopher
    WHERE philosopher=%s",
    $phl
));
```

As mentioned in another answer, `$wpdb->wp_philosophy_philosopher` is not set, which will also trigger an error, so I altered that to be `{$wpdb->prefix}philosophy_philosopher`.

If you had [debugging enabled](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983) you would have spotted these issues yourself. It is a good idea to enable debugging during development, and preferably on a development server.