# Wordpress can only query up to 766

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query

Basically, I am little unaware of my WP can only run a query up to 766 custom post of one type (the actual posts).

I have 26,000 posts that are within one custom post type, but cannot query them all as it only allows me to query the first 766 and then stops on number 767.

Has anyone faced this problem before? If any idea on how it could be fixed?

EDIT:

From some of the comments I have debugged the website and found no errors to my query problem.I have used define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); and got no where.

The public can be found here: http://universitycompare.com/test/

As you see here it is only showing 766 custom posts, but when it gets to 767 the query stops and does not work form there on.  I need a way to set the Reading settings of 'Blog pages show at most' to unlimited. (or 30k+)

Also just FYI, the code i'm using to query can be found here:

```
<?php //wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

<?php 

// args
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'uc_course',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $object = get_field('university') ?>
        <?php if( $object->post_title == "University of Aberdeen" ) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

Comment: _Types_, not individual _posts_? Please elaborate how are you querying and how you came to 766 number.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? I am guessing you are looking at a memory problem or server timeout but without more information it is just a guess.

Comment: @Rarst they are 26,000 of custom posts in one custom post type, but my query just stops. I get no error, it just stops at 767 and I cannot work out why.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - I do really know my way around wordpress but I've never had a problem like this that has had to be debugged. How would I use a debug script to help me with my query problem.

Comment: I'm guessing I could use: define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); but where would this be placed?

Comment: The code goes in `wp-config.php`. Follow the link I posted and follow the instructions, or look here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376

Comment: Yup done that, it's not displayign errors but only wp_enqueue_script error and nothing else.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I have updated question with a web link and a better explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: What is `var_dump($the_query->found_posts);`?

Comment: Thats not in the code and it just prints the code in front-end.