# Custom plugin breaks css.php on Multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite, metabox

I got a strange problem on a Multisite Install I run.

Everything works perfectly fine (Domain Mapping, Caching, whatever functions and Plugins I use, both forced and chooseable).

To enhance the experience for my customers, I installed a simple autoexpiry plugin that I wrote myself quite a while ago. It is not the best solution of entering a date, but apart from the UI it just works.

In my plugin I include two files:

- cronjobs.php (containing the function for the one-off event to set the post to draft)
- metaboxes.php (containing the custom metabox for the post, as well as the save-function, and the hooks to use them).

Now the strange part:
In WordPress-Admin everything works just as expected. The scheduling of the events to set a post to draft, and the metabox.

The Theme for my Multisite contains a `css.php`, rendering the custom CSS from the Theme options. If the Plugin is activated, **only this file** gets a `404`.

I already built a workaround, including the file for the metaboxes just in admin. Now the `css.php` works. My main plugin file looks like this now:

```
include('inc/cronjobs.php');
if ( is_admin() ) { // I just include the metaboxes.php in the admin section now
    include('inc/metaboxes.php');
}
```

Without the conditional for the `include` of the metaboxes file, the debug throws this Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /www/htdocs/w009bb74/landingpages/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1342
```

Has anyone had a similar problem? I can't figure out what's the problem here. On singlesite installs there is no problem whatsoever. The `css.php` in the theme does not even work if the `metaboxes.php` is **completely empty**

Here are the two files:

`cronjobs.php`

```
function f711_autoexpiry_set_draft( $post_id ) {
    $post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'draft'
    );
    wp_update_post( $post );
}
add_action( 'f711_autoexpiry_event', 'f711_autoexpiry_set_draft', 10, 1 );
```

`metaboxes.php`

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'f711_autoexpiry_expiry_add_custom_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'f711_autoexpiry_expiry_save_expirydata' );

function f711_autoexpiry_expiry_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'f711_autoexpiry_expiry_sectionid',
        __( 'Ablaufdatum', 'f711' ),
        'f711_autoexpiry_expiry_inner_custom_box',
        'angebote' ,
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

function f711_autoexpiry_expiry_inner_custom_box( $post ) {

  // Use nonce for verification
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'f711_autoexpiry_expiry_nonce' );

  $expirydate = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_f711_autoexpiry_expirydate', true );

  if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_f711_autoexpiry_expirydate', true ) != "" ) {
    $expirydate = strtotime( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_f711_autoexpiry_expirydate', true ) );
    $expiryday = date( 'd', $expirydate );
    $expirymonth = date( 'm', $expirydate );
    $expiryyear = date( 'Y', $expirydate );
    $expiryhour = date( 'H', $expirydate );
    $expiryminute = date( 'i', $expirydate );
  }

  $styles = 'style="width: 40px;margin-right:8px;"';
  $styleslabel = 'style="width: 40px;margin-right:10px;float:left;"';
  // The actual fields for data entry
  echo '<label for="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_tag" ' . $styleslabel . '>';
       _e("Tag", 'f711_du' );
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<label for="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_monat"' . $styleslabel . '>';
       _e("Mon.", 'f711_du' );
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<label for="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_jahr"' . $styleslabel . '>';
       _e("Jahr", 'f711_du' );
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<label for="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_stunde"' . $styleslabel . '>';
       _e("Stu.", 'f711_du' );
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<label for="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_minute"' . $styleslabel . '>';
       _e("Min.", 'f711_du' );
  echo '</label><br />';
  echo '<input type="text" id="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_tag" name="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_tag" value="' . $expiryday . '" size="2" ' . $styles . ' />';
  echo '<input type="text" id="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_monat" name="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_monat" value="' . $expirymonth . '" size="2" ' . $styles . ' />';
  echo '<input type="text" id="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_jahr" name="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_jahr" value="' . $expiryyear . '" size="2" ' . $styles . ' />';
  echo '<input type="text" id="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_stunde" name="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_stunde" value="' . $expiryhour . '" size="2" ' . $styles . ' />';
  echo '<input type="text" id="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_minute" name="f711_autoexpiry_expiry_minute" value="' . $expiryminute . '" size="2" ' . $styles . ' />';
  echo '<br /><br />';
  echo '<input type="checkbox" id="f711_autoexpiry_clear_expiry" name="f711_autoexpiry_clear_expiry" value="clear"> Ablaufdatum löschen';
  echo '<br /><br />';
  echo '<p>Format: z.B. 31 03 2014 07 00</p>';
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function f711_autoexpiry_expiry_save_expirydata( $post_id ) {

  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['f711_autoexpiry_expiry_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;

  if ( $_POST['f711_autoexpiry_clear_expiry'] == 'clear' || $_POST['f711_autoexpiry_expiry_tag'] == "" ) {
      delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_f711_autoexpiry_expirydate' );
      wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'f711_autoexpiry_event', array( $post_id ) );
      return;
  }

  $tag = $_POST['f711_autoexpiry_expiry_tag'];
  $monat = $_POST['f711_autoexpiry_expiry_monat'];
  $jahr = $_POST['f711_autoexpiry_expiry_jahr'];
  $stunde = $_POST['f711_autoexpiry_expiry_stunde'];
  $minute = $_POST['f711_autoexpiry_expiry_minute'];

  if( substr( $tag, 0, 1 ) != "0" && $tag < 10) $tag = "0" . $tag;
  if( substr( $monat, 0, 1 ) != "0" && $monat < 10) $monat = "0" . $monat;
  if( substr( $stunde, 0, 1 ) != "0" && $stunde < 10) $stunde = "0" . $stunde;
  if( substr( $minute, 0, 1 ) != "0" && $minute < 10) $minute = "0" . $minute;
  $usedate = $jahr . '-' . $monat . '-' . $tag . ' ' . $stunde . ':' . $minute . ':00';
  if ( $jahr > 2000 && $tag > "00" && $monat > "00" && $usedate != "1970-01-01" ) {
      update_post_meta( $post_id, '_f711_autoexpiry_expirydate', $usedate );
  }
  $offset = '-' . get_option('gmt_offset') . ' hour';
  $thisdate = strtotime( $offset , strtotime( $usedate ) );
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'f711_autoexpiry_event', array( $post_id ) );
    wp_schedule_single_event( $thisdate, 'f711_autoexpiry_event', array( $post_id ) );
}
```

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)?

Comment: One strange error occurs in Debug (updated the question).