# Problems with installing and deleting plugins

Tags: plugins, headers, activation, ftp, customization

When I want to install a plugin from the web interface, I receive the error

> The plugin does not have a valid header.

or

> Destination folder already exists.

after it has been downloaded and I click on "activate".

When I delete a plugin, the plugin gets deactivated, but isn't deleted from my FTP server.

What's the problem with my WordPress installation? File permissions are OK on my server.

I've modified class-wp-upgrader.php so that it always removes old files.

P. S.: My plugin directory is empty now, and I still get the message the the folder already exists.

Comment: This happens with any plugin your try? Or only with one? Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)?

Comment: @s_ha_dum This happens with every plugin. When I enable debugging information, nothing new is printed (I can only reproduce the second error now). Can I somehow clear a plugin cache?

Comment: Log errors to a file. `echo`ed errors do not always print for backend actions. I don't know what "plugin cache" you mean.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I don't know, I'm new to WordPress.
I've modified `class-wp-upgrader.php` so that it always removes old files. WordPress tells me that the installation was finished, but still there is no plugin. :-(

Comment: ok... hacking core files is always wrong. It sounds like you may have created your own problem. Put things back the way they were. If you need to always delete files, do some research and ask a question about how to do that correctly.

Comment: @s_ha_dum The hacking was done when I already had the problem. I was trying to find a solution with it.