# My website resets when accessing the index page

Tags: cache, cookies, reset

So my wordpress theme and website is on a stage server, since it's under production. And this issue happens once in a while.

Basically, if I log in as a user, and when I enter the index page, the site resets (front end). It appears as if I'm logged out, and some of the changes on the actual index page (including the header and footer) are not being shown. This only happens when clicking on the index page, either view a link or typing the actual address. If I click on another link, or access another page, suddenly everything is back to normal. But then if I enter the index page again, the same problems occurs.

Anyone got any ideas? I'm using W3 Total Cache. Can it be a cache issue or a cookie issue? I'm clueless since the problem only seems to occur randomly, and sometimes completely disappear.

The only error I get is: [11-Feb-2014 13:07:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: raw_welcome_message_text in /storage/content/40/10769050/stage.12345.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/stage.12345.com/index.php on line 29

I just solved this with the php empty. I doubt that this has anything to do with the actual problem though.

Comment: Are you showing and logging errors? This seems very specific to your install, I can't think of what could completely knock out header and footer.

Comment: [Do you have debugging information?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)

Comment: Ok, I've activated the debuglog. The only error I get is: