# What tool are available in the wordpress API for debugging a plugin?

Tags: plugins, debug

I am very new to plugin development.  I have created my first plugin but when I activated it, it caused the majority of every page on the site to stop being generated.  I have echoed something from the end of the php script to confirm that it was completing without an error.  But other than that I have no idea what I should do to debug this problem.

I would like to be able to work on this on a public site that will be getting traffic while I work, is there a way I can have the plugin only activated on one page or only for me and not for guests?

I would like to be able to show debug messages, is there a convenient way to do this?

Are there points outside of my plugin that would be helpful for debugging?  I don't know where to look that might be leading to the problems.

Comment: I am fairly sure that this question is a functional duplicate of [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/95982/21376).

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, I couldn't find it with what I was searching, it doesn't have the most useful title/tags in my opinion.

Comment: You can suggest a different title. The community will vote your change in, or reject it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. You should *NEVER* work on a live site

Just setup a local installation of [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info) and do your testing there. This has a lot of benefits:

- You can't break a live site
- You don't need to upload changed files
- It runs faster as everything is local and doesn't go trough the internet

### 2. Debugging

First you could enable debug in *config.php*

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

This will give you a lot more information **what** went wrong if something goes wrong.

There also is a lot more info in the WordPress Codex on [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: How will the debug out be rendered when I do this?  I've done this and the only errors I see are wamp errors.  Is wamp interfering with WordPress errors?