# Displaying number of search results for each post type

Tags: search, pre-get-posts

Using the code below, my search returns results from two different CPTs. How can I display the number of results for each CPT before displaying results?

```
function more_posts_per_search_page( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_search ) {
            $query->set( array( 'posts_per_page' => 500, 'post_type' => array( 'author', 'book' ) ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','more_posts_per_search_page' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your callback to `pre_get_posts` is wrong. That is [not the way that `set` works](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2136). If you had [debugging enabled](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983), you'd see `Notices`. It should be:

```
function more_posts_per_search_page( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_search ) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page',500);
            $query->set('post_type',array( 'author', 'book'));
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','more_posts_per_search_page' );
```

Second, there is nothing built in that I am aware of that will return those numbers to you, but it isn't hard to do using a [WordPress Core function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) and a [PHP one](https://www.php.net/array_count_values).

```
$types = wp_list_pluck($wp_query->posts,'post_type');
// var_dump($types); // debugging
$types_count = array_count_values($types);
var_dump($types_count); // your data
```

That code should be placed in your theme's `search.php`.

Comment: Perfect as usual. Just enabled debugging on all my sites in progress, thanks for that too.

Comment: Well... "perfect" is the target but not always the fact. Thanks for that though :)