# problem with blank page

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, post-thumbnails, publish

i have a real big problem with my wordpress website functions.php when i put the following code to achive post view and thumbnail. i'm getting the blank page error which when i publish or update a post i get blank white page. i am searching and the result was that the blank page while publish or update means there is a problem in functions.php when i cut all of the code from the functions.php file resave it. the blank page problem will solved. 
this is my functions.php code and seems there is not error:

```
﻿<?php 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
        $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }
    }
    //To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
    function wpb_track_post_views ($post_id) {
        if ( !is_single() ) return;
        if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
            global $post;
            $post_id = $post->ID;   
        }
        wpb_set_post_views($post_id);
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_views');
    function wpb_get_post_views($postID){
        $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            return "تعداد بازدید:"."0";
        }
        return 'تعداد بازدید:'.$count;
    }
?>
```

Comment: [Do you have debugging information?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)

Comment: Turn wp debug on so that you can get better errors: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress