# Using database in new instalation

Tags: backup

I have a Wordpress instance in my production environment.

I have created a new raw instalation in my development machine, and I have imported the database from production.

I have changed the wp_options table to make sure that the site_url and home are actually pointing to the named url I have in my local machine. However, when I access the site, it doesn't show up anything.

What am I missing or need to do?

Comment: You need to run a full find and replace, search this site.  You'll also need to pull the production site down if you want to themes and plugins.

Comment: Find and replace of what? Why would I need to pull the production site down?

Comment: Find and replace of the database, the url is stored all throughout the thing.  By pulling down I mean make a copy.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Enable
   debugging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)
   so that you can spot problems.
2. [Alter the database connection information in `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Default_wp-config-sample.php)

   ```
   // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
   /** The name of the database for WordPress */
   define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

   /** MySQL database username */
   define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

   /** MySQL database password */
   define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

   /** MySQL hostname */
   define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
   ```
3. You can eliminate some issues by hard-coding a couple of web
   addresses also. If you are having a connection problem, I would recommend it.

   ```
   define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress' );
   define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/wordpress' );
   ```
4. Alter the embedded link URLs with a plugin like "Velvet Blues Update
   Urls"

Additional  work may need to be done depending on Item #1

Comment: I do not see this line: ``define( 'WP_SITEURL' in my wp-config.php`` file. Where should that be?

Comment: When I have entered the database, and try to access www.mm-blog.local/wp-admin, it changes the URL for: ``http://www.mm-blog.local/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmm-blog.local%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`` but says 'this webpage is not available'

Comment: @HommerSmith : See the edit.  I actually skipped part of what I was intending to write.

Comment: Important to notice, that I dont see anything in the error logs of apache. I see the following in the access logs: ``127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2014:15:07:09 -0800] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -``

Comment: I dont think is a problem of database connection. Before I copy the production database, I can actually do all the installation correctly within my local database.

Comment: I suspect item #3 but really solving this may take hands-on server access.