# Incomplete attachment page

Tags: attachments, images, server-load

I am using the twenty-thirteen theme and my attachment page chops off the footer & image. Have a look at my screenshot. You can see that it shows the title but it doesn't show the image and the footer is missing. Also the admin bar is missing too. What I do notice it takes roughtly 10 seconds to load any attachment pages. I have around 400k images in my media library. Anyone know what the problem is?[image]

mysql error log:

```
140318  2:05:58  InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is 9440466,
InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity 9433498.
InnoDB: If you are using big BLOB or TEXT rows, you must set the
InnoDB: combined size of log files at least 10 times bigger than the
InnoDB: largest such row.
```

Comment: You have a serious error. Post [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376) please.

Comment: I did that but there's no errors in my error log

Comment: Maybe your image paths are wrong or the CSS is broken. I don't know what to tell you without more information.

Comment: image path & css are correct cause I'm using the themes that came with the core. I do notice is that it loads the attachment page very slow. I don't know if 400k images is causing slow load

Comment: have you checked your MySQL error log?

Comment: @Milo I added the mysql error log to the first post. I don't know what settings to change to get rid of the error