# "No Data Received" error in Chrome every time i try to update the theme functions file

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options, theme-customizer

Under Appearance --> Editor --> functions.php ( Theme functions ), whenever i try to modify a piece of code in it and click Update, i get this "No Data Received" error in Chrome. I never get this error when i click on any other area in WordPress or theme options, custom css etc.

I don't know why i am getting this error. I use GoDaddy hosting.
Can someone please help me out on this issue.

Thanks !

Comment: This is most likely a hosting problem and hence [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [wordpress.se].

Comment: This _might_ be a hosting problem. Please provide [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)

Comment: @s_ha_dum is right of course, should have been a bit more specific than I've been, but we'll see after you provide additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted GoDaddy support and they advised me to login to the hosting manager and make the edits to the functions.php file from there. That way it worked !

Though i still couldn't figure out why i was getting that problem when i tried to edit it from within my WordPress dashboard, but anyways the problem is solved now.

Thank you @ialocin and @s_ha_dum for your help !