# Plugin Install screeen not found

Tags: plugins

I have been trying to add a new plugin by going to

```
http://domain.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php
```

But This gives me "Error 404 - Page NOT Found" error, which is being shown using the theme 404 file (That's what I understand as the page adapts the theme styling).

The same happens when I try to load update-core.php , themes.php etc.

Any idea why this happens?

**UPDATE**

I updated my `wp-config.php` for debugging purpose and I have the following notice being displayed.

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/travel5b/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 29`

Comment: What is the role of the user you are logged in as?

Comment: @s_ha_dum admin

Comment: Disable all of your plugins (if there are already plugins running) and add [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983) to the question.

Comment: Can you confirm the plugin-install.php file exists in the file sytem and is readable?

Comment: The files are there, and they have 0644 permissions.

Also, this seems to be a common issue thrown since 3.8 ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+plugins+page+not+found&oq=wordpress+plugins+page+no&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2j69i60l3.12933j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=wordpress+plugins.php+page+not+found) ).