# Upacking the package... stalls, but installs plugin

Tags: plugins, installation, core

I have been searching high and low for the correct solution to my problem. I have found many searches relating to this, but can not find a solution...

Here is the Updated Video to see what happens ?

http://youtu.be/ILkaSyxFaDs

When installing plugins or themes , it will get to the page:

```
"Unpacking the package..."
```

[image]

and then just stalls. Nothing else happens.

**The Plugin or Theme Installs just fine, but it doesn't output the correct info on this "update.php" page.**

I have tried to edit my .htaccess page, increase memory_limit and a bunch of other tips that I found from searches.

I even tried to install a fresh Wordpress and the problem still persists.

Here is a snapshot of the source code of where the page stops loading from every time.

Thanks in advance.. my head is spinning...

**EDIT: 
Here is the debug info I am receiving:**

> [24-Mar-2014 14:51:18] PHP Notice:  ob_end_flush() [ref.outcontrol]: failed to delete buffer
>   zlib output compression. in
>   /home/web/public_html/store/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2773

[image]

Comment: [Debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)?

Comment: I will try all three constants. I tried the debug=true, but nothign

Comment: ok, looked at the debug log and looks like:
[24-Mar-2014 14:51:18] PHP Notice:  ob_end_flush() [<a href='ref.outcontrol'>ref.outcontrol</a>]: failed to delete buffer zlib output compression. in /home/website/public_html/store/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2773

Comment: @eberswine I do think that this is not linked to our theme or wordpress. I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is something on the server side. You should contact your hosting provider. Just one request, if you come to a solution, it would be nice if you can add it as an answer

Comment: I updated a video for this question.. tried server side fixes, but nothing.. ?