# Can I use multiple nav_walkers?

Tags: navigation, walker

I am working on a project and I came to the conclusion that I need to use 3 nav walkers:

- one for edit and
- 2 for HTML formatting

`class MY_Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit extends Walker_Nav_Menu {} // this extends the menu item edit and adds some custom fields`

next is

`class MY_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {} // this extends the HTML formatting in the front-end for main navigation and using the custom fields values`

last one is

`class MY_Walker_Nav_Menu_Footer extends Walker_Nav_Menu {} // same as the above just used for another menu in the footer`

Currently all walkers in one file and it does not work.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Yes. You can use as many as you like. Now [edit] the question with more specifics, please.

Comment: Edited. Now more info, please check out.

Comment: The code you posted is fine but it is missing all of the interesting parts. Post [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)

Comment: Well, it's that simple, check out the nav-menu.php from wp includes, there is a first class extending the Nav_Walker. This is my edit walker. The others are this https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navlist-walker and this https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker. I have everything working now. Have fun.

Comment: Its "what" simple? I know how nav walkers work. I just don't know why yours (I guess only one is your actually) are broken, as you didn't post any useful code. Am I correct in assuming it was a syntax error?

Comment: No no, don't worry, I solved the problem because now I know which one was it. Details here https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/issues/90