# Hardcoding links to wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, plugin-wpml

I am currently trying to add a some links to the end of my wp_nav_menu but am having a hard time with the callback function that creates the list of languages I want to insert. The first function is from a WPML plugin and works correctly anywhere else.

```
function lang_selector_links(){

$languages=icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code');

    if(!empty ($languages)){

        foreach ($languages as $language){
            echo '<li><a href="' . $language['url'] . '" title="' . $language['translated_name'] . '"<img src="' . $language['country_flag_url'] . ' alt="' .$language['language_code'] . '"/>'. $language['language_code']. '</a></li>';
        }

    } else {
        echo 'no languages';
    }
} 

function my_lang_links( $items, $args ) {
        $lang_list= lang_selector_links();

        $items .= '<li>' . $lang_list . '</li>';

    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','my_lang_links', 10, 2);
```

If I call `lang_selector_links()`in any other context it works as expected and outputs a list of supported languages but I can't seem to call it within the filter.

**Edit: It turns out that it is outputting them only I was expecting the links to be part of the unordered list that contains the other menu items. Instead it adds them before.**

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)? Also, if the problem is that a third party plugin function doesn't work, this may be off topic.

Comment: No the third party function works fine. I've used it outside of wp-menu without problems. I'm not getting any errors just an empty `<li></li>`.

Comment: This is a PHP issue. Your `lang_selector_links` function `echo`es output, and you try to assign that to a variable in `my_lang_links` function. That will only work if your `lang_selector_links` function `return`s its value.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It works correctly if I return a value rather than echoing it. Of course if I simply change echo to return I'll only get one value so I suppose I need to push them into an array?

Comment: you could use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).