# WordPress not updating post or disable plugin instead a white page appear

Tags: plugins, posts

I was working in a local WordPress website, and it works without any problem. Then i uploaded it to a live server as follow:

- Uploaded all my local files and folder to the live server.
- Imported the local DB to Live server.
- Changed the links in the DB from the (localhost) to my (live domain).
- changed the config.php file to connect to the DB.

after doing these steps my web site **( Front-end ) is working great without any problem**.

But when i logged-in to my dashboard and tried to do any of the following **i got instead a white page appear without any error**:

- When trying to **disable/activate** any plugin.
- When trying to **Update** any post.
- When trying to **publish new** page/post.
- When **Deleting** page/post.

I tried **this solutions but didn't solve the problem**:

- I disabled all the plugin to see if any cause a conflict.
- I tried to use the default theme instead of my custom theme.

**Update:**

After enabling `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` as @s_ha_dum say, I got this :

- **Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /......./wp-content/themes/sbr/functions.php:670) in /......../wp-admin/post.php on line 233.
- **Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ............/wp-content/themes/sbr/functions.php:670) in /............./wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896.

Comment: [Enable debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983). Check your server logs if you have access.

Comment: After doing as @s_ha_dum say, I got this :

1. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started .../functions.php:670) in ..../wp-admin/post.php on line 233

2. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ..../functions.php:670) in ...../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896

Comment: Please [edit] that error into the question. Formatting in comments is very minimal.