# cannot upload anything into wordpress

Tags: uploads

I have worpdress 3.8.1. sometimes when i try to upload image, pdf using worpdress functions it gets stuck at 100% and nothing gets logged in the log files so i d onot know what the problem is. however I have seen the following which appear randomly, picture attached[image]

Comment: "sometimes when i try to upload image, pdf " -- would that "sometimes" correspond to times when you try to upload very large images or pdfs?

Comment: no, file is approx `344kb`

Comment: Do you have root access to the server? And to server logs? Have you [enabled debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983) on the site?

Comment: i think i found the culprit. `http-authentication` plugin. not sure what it does but it was enabled and ticked as active, so i just unticked it

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and come back after 2 days to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the culprit. `http-authentication` plugin. not sure what it does but it was enabled and ticked as active, so i just unticked it.