# Editing wp-config.php file asks for another installation

Tags: wp-config

I edited wp-config.php and now I can't access my existing site and I see the Wordpress installation page! Help! How do I get to my existing site?

Comment: check table prefix. wp_ or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[(s)FTP](https://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients) into your site, or use a file manager provided by your host, and undo what you did.

1. Then, if you were editing PHP with the built in editor as I suspect,
   *don't ever do that again-- ever*. It is like working on an airplane while it is in the air.
2. [Create a local copy of your site and work locally](https://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress). Upload to
   the host when you know the code works.
3. If you [enable debugging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983), you should see clues as to where you
   went wrong, but you may not be able to do that in your case as it is
   the config file that is broken.

Without knowing specifically what you changed and how you changed it, that is all I've got.