# single.php not pulling in any data from database

Tags: database, single

My single.php doesnt seem to be fulling any information through from the database for the current post. here is my single.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="main-container">
<div class="main wrapper clearfix">
<article>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <header>
        <h1>Stats for <?php echo get_the_id();?><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p> <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?> </p>
<?php endif; ?>
</article>                  

<?php get_sidebar();?>          

            </div> <!-- #main -->
        </div> <!-- #main-container -->


<?php get_footer();?>
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: What do mean. Your code displays the title and post ID next to the post title as expected. What do you expect it to display

Comment: echo get_the_id and the_title return nothing...

Comment: Enable debug by setting debug to true in wp-config.php. Your code works fine on my side.

Comment: Add [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983) please.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the actual rendered output of that code, or provide a live link that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score -2):

have_posts() needs a Wordpress database query before it will show anything, check it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function%5fReference/have%5fposts) like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post' );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
        echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

it will display all posts in your blog.

Comment: Not true. `single.php` is only included if the main query indicates `is_single()`. The main query has already been parsed, and post(s) fetched, before determining which template to include. For `single.php`, that main query will be a single blog post.

Comment: please check that code in a blog with single.php file, because I checked it and I am sure he has not included it in main query

Comment: The main query already exists in template-hierarchy template files. It is found in the `$wp_query` global, which is referenced by default when calling `have_posts()`.

Comment: yes I know if this file is in any theme's directory ie in template-hierarchy that is true but if this file is not in any theme directory then I am right

Comment: If it's not in any Theme directory, then where would it be?

Comment: There's all kinds of reasons why single.php may not be showing visible results while within the template hierarchy. Something could be filtering the main query before template_redirect. Inspect the globals $post and $wp_query as well as the offending SQL. It's not really necessary to run another WP_Query instance if you can sort out the issues with your main query, unless of course you need a subsequent, second query.