# apache cpu over 70% on localhost

Tags: php, apache, fatal-error, sass

i'm running a number of WP sites on my localhost WAMP on w8.
I started to work on a new site, using Sass and Zurb Foundation using this template: http://jointswp.com/.

the problem:
During my work, suddenly every time I'm querying from the index page, the apache server takes up to 70% from my cpu and the page doesn't load.
It happens only on this site, only on this specipic page.

This is the code from the index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="inner-content" class="row clearfix">
        <?php $caruselq = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'action') );?>
            <?php if ( $caruselq->have_posts() ) : while ( $caruselq->have_posts() ) :?>
                <?php include get_stylesheet_directory().'/tryout.php';//carusel?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else: ?>

        <?php endif;?>
        <div id="main" class="large-8 medium-8 columns clearfix" role="main">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div> <!-- end #inner-content -->
            </div> <!-- end #content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and the code from tryout.php:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :?>
  <ul class="example-orbit" data-orbit data-options="slide_number:false;">
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <div class="orbit-caption">
      <?php the_excerpt();?>
    </div>
    </li>
      <?php endwhile;?>
  </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Here is the log from apache during the problem:

```
1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:38 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:40 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/plugins.php HTTP/1.1" 200 43845
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:44 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,thickbox,plugin-install,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,underscore,shortcode,media-upload&ver=3.9 HTTP/1.1" 200 21434
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:49 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=delete-selected&checked%5B0%5D=akismet%2Fakismet.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=8adc278390 HTTP/1.1" 200 29629
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:51 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,thickbox,underscore,shortcode,media-upload&ver=3.9 HTTP/1.1" 200 21188
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:53 +0300] "POST /egood/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=delete-selected&checked%5B0%5D=akismet%2Fakismet.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=8adc278390 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:53 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/plugins.php?deleted=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s= HTTP/1.1" 200 42329
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:54 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/bhittani-framework/admin/js/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:54 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/bhittani-framework/admin/js/lightbox.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:54 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/bhittani-framework/admin/js/admin.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:54 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/bhittani-framework/admin/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:54 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=3.9 HTTP/1.1" 200 40221
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:05:54 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,thickbox,plugin-install,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,underscore,shortcode,media-upload&ver=3.9 HTTP/1.1" 200 21434
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:06:55 +0300] "POST /egood/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:07:27 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=deactivate&plugin=jetpack%2Fjetpack.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=0cc932eb63 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:07:28 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s= HTTP/1.1" 200 41519
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:07:46 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=deactivate&plugin=kk-star-ratings%2Findex.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=5d232328de HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:07:47 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s= HTTP/1.1" 200 38436
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:07:47 +0300] "GET /egood/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,thickbox,plugin-install,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check&ver=3.9 HTTP/1.1" 200 14928
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:08:48 +0300] "POST /egood/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47
::1 - - [19/Apr/2014:18:09:48 +0300] "POST /egood/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47
```

Ive been trying to generate log file from WP by changing the WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG but it does not generate...

Here is MYSQL log file from today:

```
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 105484389
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-04-19 16:43:50 7000 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-04-19 16:43:51 7000 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-04-19 16:43:51 7000 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.12-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: "At one point that I can't remember, something went wrong. Help!?!?!" is not much of a trouble ticket. Check you server logs, provide [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)

Comment: Is that an error log from a time period when you observe the problem? And what about MySQL logs?

Answer (score 1):

Your tryout.php has a posts loop in it, and you're calling that file inside another loop. Loops squared. I expect your content is not actually structured in this way?