# When I click edit on a post, all the content disappear. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: posts, database, migration, visual-editor, post-editor

I am working on a site: greatlakesecho.org
When I try to edit a post, the content just disappears from the visual editor.  I am running the latest version of Word Press but this happened on the previous version as well.  I am using the Project Largo theme with the site.

The site was recently migrated from to a new host and has gone an overhaul into a responsive design.  This first started happening when I changed the character encoding to remove odd symbols from the posts.  I was successful in that by changing it to utf16.  At this point only older posts that were created before the migration would disappear when I clicked edit.  I have since updated to the latest version of Word Press and it happens to every post.

I have tried removing all the plugins but no luck.
Tried different themes with no luck.
Tried repairing the database from cPanel.

Here is the debugging info:

WordPress database error: [Table 'greatlak_wp776.wp_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist]
SELECT `lockout_host` FROM `wp_itsec_lockouts` WHERE `lockout_active`=1 AND `lockout_expire_gmt` > '2014-04-22 19:52:36' AND `lockout_host`='35.9.132.246';

WordPress database error: [Table 'greatlak_wp776.wp_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist]
SELECT `lockout_user` FROM `wp_itsec_lockouts` WHERE `lockout_active`=1 AND `lockout_expire_gmt` > '2014-04-22 19:52:36' AND `lockout_user`=93;

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've followed the instructions in your link.

Comment: And? Any errors?

Comment: WordPress database error: [Table 'greatlak_wp776.wp_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist]
SELECT `lockout_host` FROM `wp_itsec_lockouts` WHERE `lockout_active`=1 AND `lockout_expire_gmt` > '2014-04-22 19:52:36' AND `lockout_host`='35.9.132.246';

---------------------------------------------------------

WordPress database error: [Table 'greatlak_wp776.wp_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist]
SELECT `lockout_user` FROM `wp_itsec_lockouts` WHERE `lockout_active`=1 AND `lockout_expire_gmt` > '2014-04-22 19:52:36' AND `lockout_user`=93;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the Navis Media Credit plugin manually.  I searched through the plugins folder using WinSCP and apparently when I was removing all the plugins using the WordPress admin panel, this one wasn't actually getting removed.  This plugin was conflicting with the theme I am using and learned this by deleting all the plugins and using one of the default WP themes.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong with your migration. A plugin-- [I think it is this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/)-- does not have the table(s) it needs to operate. I assume that some tables were not transfered. Disable that plugin, then reactivate it and this should clear up. I assume that the plugin will create its tables on re-activation.

If you can't get to the backend to disable it, just delete it or rename the directory, then reinstall it.