# Problems With Query and/or Template Part and/or PHP

Tags: php, loop, templates, query

I'm trying to show only the last article.

I made content-latestnews.php and it worked before meddling with queries. Template part was shown, but after I tryed to show the actual content it would show page up to the query part.

Category 1 (which is vesti (*ser*.) = news) is there, there is like dozens of posts in that category.

Nevertheless, it doesn't show anything even if query is left out.

I'm using Wordpress 3.9.

I've tried with:

```
<?php
$lastnews = new WP_Query('showposts=1&cat=1');
if ( $lastnews->have_posts() ) : while ( $lastnews->have_posts() ) : $lastnews->the_post();
    // Include the latest news template.
    get_template_part( 'content', 'latestnews' );
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata()
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    $lastnews = new WP_Query('showposts=1&cat=1');
    while ( $lastnews->have_posts() ) : $lastnews->the_post();
        // Include the latest news template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'latestnews' );
    endwhile;
?>
```

I even tried without query

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Include the latest news template.
    get_template_part( 'content', 'latestnews' );
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

and

```
<?php

if ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Include the latest news template.
    get_template_part( 'content', 'latestnews' );
endif;
?>
```

Thank you for your time. This should be bare basic, but obviously I'm missing something simple.

Comment: 1) Are your sure the template is being loaded at all? 2) Have you tried just dumping the data-- `var_dump($lastnews);` 3) Do you have [debugging enabled](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)? 4)`showposts` is long since deprecated. Use `posts_per_page`.

Comment: In your first example, why are you running the custom query twice? Also, you con't call `wp_reset_postdata()` after the second iteration. Where is the **actual failure** taking place? Is the template part file being included or *not* being included? If it *is* being included, please **edit your question** to include its markup, and describe where within that markup the failure is taking place.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time.

I've been away from Wordpress for so long that I've used obsolete commands and forgot about basic steps in setting up dev environment.

With debug turned on, I've found the problem in blink of an eye - one semicolon was inside instead of outside of the bracket in template file.

`<?php the_content( __('Nastavite čitati <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>'); ) ?>`