# How To Get Search Term and Use in Function

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm trying to write a function that will 'grab'
the search term entered into the blog search form,
and then hook the function to the `get_search_query` filter
like this `add_filter('get_search_query','myFunction');` so that
everytime a search is made, 'myFunction' runs and grabs the search term
(or so I think), I have this line in myFunction to grab the search term

`$search_term = get_search_query();`

but it seems to be causing problem, the blog doesn't display, except
I comment that particular line out. What is the right way to achieve
the subject. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
function myFunction(){
global $wpdb;
$search_term = get_search_query();
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "tableName"; 
$insert = "INSERT into $table(`serach_term`) VALUES ('$search_term')";
$wpdb->query($insert);   
}

add_filter('get_search_query','myFunction');
```

Comment: Do you have [debugging enabled](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)? Please post _all_ of the relevant code.

Comment: Edit that code into the question please.

Comment: And the debugging information

Comment: I enabled debugging but I didn't get any message or logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a filter to `get_search_query`, and within that function calling `get_search_query`, which runs your filter, which calls `get_search_query`, which runs your filter, which calls `get_search_query`, which runs your filter… do you see the problem here?

The search query is passed to the filter as an argument, so you don't need to fetch it-

```
function myFunction($search_term){
    // now you can use $search_term directly in your code
}
add_filter('get_search_query','myFunction');
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Just a new issue that arose-the function gets executed multiple times, sometimes thrice, sometimes 4 times

Comment: Never mind. Fixed