# Related posts meta_query CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

i have two post type "Artists" and "Songs", in "Songs" i have a meta box with checkbox list of "Artists" names.

i want to show related posts if any post have same value of post meta with artist name:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
global $post;
$artist_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "artist_name", true);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('songs'),
    'meta_key' => $artist_name
);

$query = new WP_Query;
return $query;
```

query should display posts with same value of meta box automatic.

this is possible ?!

more info:

[image: post type of artists names:]

[image: Meta box of artists names in Songs post type]

[image: Showing related songs by artists name in single page]

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work? If not, what happens? By "query" I assume you mean `WP_Query`? Do you have [debugging enabled](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)?

Comment: yes i have WP_Query, it not working, i tried 'meta_key' => 'artist_name' but always it showing all posts and not from meta key.

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code? I don't see any wp_query in here... Do you modify args later?

Comment: $artist_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "artist_name", true);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('songs'),
    'meta_key' => $artist_name,
);   $query = new WP_Query;   return $query;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
$artist_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "artist_name", true);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('songs'),
    'meta_key' => $artist_name,
);
$related = new WP_Query($args);
```

In your question you state that you want posts that "have same ***value*** of post meta with artist name". What the code above does is not search for values associated with the key but for key names matching the artist. Try:

```
$artist_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "artist_name", true);
var_dump($artist_name);    
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('songs'),
    'meta_key' => $artist_name,
);
$related = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($related->request);
```

And you should see what is happening.

What you want instead is something like this:

```
$artist_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "artist_name", true);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('songs'),
    'meta_key' => 'artist_name',
    'meta_value' => $artist_name,
);
$related = new WP_Query($args);
```

Or a more complex but more flexible `meta_query`:

```
$artist_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "artist_name", true);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('songs'),
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'artist_name',
        'value' => $artist_name,
      )
    )
);
$related = new WP_Query($args);
```

I'd lean toward the `meta_query` as it nicely encapsulates the related "meta" arguments, and [allows for more options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

You will have to loop over the result to return anything useful, of course. For example:

```
if ($related->have_posts()) {
  while ($related->have_posts()) {
    $related->the_post();
    the_title(); 
    // etc
  }
}
```

Comment: i've tested your code and it's dont showing posts. just showing: array(1) { [71]=> string(2) "71" }

Comment: Which block of code are you referring to?

Comment: second and latest code

Comment: You should not get that result with ___any___ of my code. I tested each. The first and second block won't work. Those are to illustrate the problem. The third and fourth should. None of them should return that particular array. I don't know what you are doing but you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Third code is working :) tnx, it showing posts with same meta, Now: (mete_box is checkbox) my meta_box "artists_name" have different value example: Enrique, Rihanna, ... So i want when user are in post with Rihanna meta_box so related showing posts with this artist only. how should i change code?

Comment: You are going to have to do a better job of explaining your setup. I can't follow what you are doing.

Comment: added some screenshot, my meta_box "artists_name" does multiple names, so i want showing posts by names from metabox.