# Media Library not showing images properly

Tags: media-library

I'm trying to upload an image, but keep getting an error.  Check the attacted image.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question)

Comment: Which version of wordpress are you using, have you disabled all plugins, switched to a default theme. Does your problem go away, or does it still exists. Which images gives the error, are is just certain types, or all images, no matter what extention. Please edit your question and add relevant information

Answer (score 1):

Got home now and I had a proper look at your included image. The problem that you are experiencing is related to the naming of your images. Images, like any other files should not contain special characters as these special characters are not treated the same by operating system/file managers etc

Currently, from your image, your image is named '35-%-off.jpg'. This is why your images does not display. You should only use lowercase, hyphens, underscores and numbers as a general rule and good practice for file and image names. Spaces and special characters should, actually must, be avoided. So you can use something like this '35-percent-off.jpg` or '35percent-off.jpg'

Check out this article about "[How to Name Your Image Files](http://www.mediacollege.com/graphics/files/naming.html)". (No affiliation)

Comment: Did my question answer your problem. If so, please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark below the up/down arrows next to my answer. This will ensure that my answer not just help you, but others that will find this link. If not, is there anything regarding your question I can help with?