# WP_Query with tax_query not working

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I tried to create a custom query, but no results, it throws me an error.

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => 23,
                            )
                )
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            var_dump($query->have_posts());
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    echo the_title();
                }
            } else {
                echo 'error';
            }

            wp_reset_query();
```

I checked the documentation, but I don't know where's the problem.

The problem is the $query->have_posts() always returns false. The code is works in the header.php, but not works in functions php. I would like to know that, how to improve the code to use it in the functions.php

Comment: What is the "error" you are getting?

Comment: You say that you there is a product with term 23 assigned to it. Is this product published?

Comment: yes, I have 62 products. When I edit the taxonomy, the url is: taxonomy=product_cat&tag_ID=23&post_type=product.

Comment: We got a comment explosion in this question - I had to put it _on hold_ - because it totally is unclear what you are asking and what your problem is. Please take your time to phrase a _detailed_ [edit] that explains _the complete problem_ you are facing. Then we can reopen it.

Comment: @kaiser is it clear now?

Comment: No. You just added to the question what previously was in the comments. And as you have seen, this is much too less to understand the problem you are facing. Lean back, make yourself some tea or coffee and then try to explain it to someone who _sees and knows nothing_ of your setup. Be detailed, show lots of code, explain your setup. Else it will stay closed.

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983) There is nothing in that query that should cause it to fail in `functions.php` and it ___does___ work exactly the same when I test it. Something else is going on that is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: `wp_reset_query();` is wrong here, user `wp_reset_postdata();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

SQL query forming is wrong

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND 0 = 1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Here **1=1 AND 0 = 1**

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't help

Comment: can u provide link of front end or the exact sql query which you will get when u dump $query

Comment: From the page you are refering to - "terms (int/string/array) - Taxonomy term(s)".

Comment: http://ownaj.com/demo/

Comment: Btw I wrote the code to functions.php, is it problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why is having array(23) better then just typing 23 ?

Comment: @shahpranaf consider deleting the answer when it is completely wrong. Else it will attract downvotes.

Comment: kaiser Thanks. 
@Roberti provide debug information as I mentioned in comment. Your code is proper there is something else which is getting conflicted with it.