# pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins wont call on hosted webspace

Tags: plugins, transient

I am trying to use `pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins` to update my plugin from a GitHub repository.

For that I am using this [example](https://github.com/bfintal/Plugin-Update).
On my Dev-System (MAMP for Mac Version 2.2) everything is fine. It gets the latest Version and shows me the update notification.

When I publish it to my Live System wich is a hosted webspace package. I don’t get the Update Notification. Even after waiting 12 hours or using `?force-check=1`

What I already did was to create a simple Plugin that logs a string to the wordpress log when `pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins` is called. Again on my Dev-system it works, but not Live. So I think it has something to do with the PHP configuration.

Does anyone has an idea which setting could prevent this filter from beeing executed?

Comment: can you post code?

Comment: Are you [logging errors](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)?

Comment: I checked the logs and I could not find any errors. That ist the little plugin I wrote to check it.

`<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins test
 * Description: pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins test
 * Version: 0.1.1
 */
 
add_filter( "pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins", "echo_test" );

function echo_test(){
    error_log("pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins is triggered");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late answer, but I found the solution for my problem.

My Code was fine, also my small Test-Plugin. The problem is with the caching of my hosting provider. They are caching the Database requests and it took some time for the updater to recognize that the plugin is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old library and it looks like it relies on transient to check an/or update your plugins. This shouldn't be the case because transients are meant to store/cache temporary data.

I recommend using a more robust and mature library which we use at our company: Plugin Update Checker, see https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker

It has also an option to force check if there are any updates. This library is really flexible, you could use this for .org, github, BitBucket, GitLab and your own server.