# Adding wp_link_pages to a theme that seems to lack?

Tags: wp-link-pages

I'm using wp-bootstrap as basis to build out a custom site. The wp_link_pages function doesn't seem to work and I'm thinking maybe it's just missing from the theme. I've got a  code in a page and the template it's using has  in it but it's not working. I'm thinking maybe this functionality was stripped out of the theme.

Wondering how to put it back if this was the case. I did a search through all the theme files for wp_link_pages thinking I might find where it was declared but don't see it anywhere.

Comment: `wp_link_pages()` is a Core function. It should not just "not work". It could be filtered though. What symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: Well I have '<!–-nextpage–->' in a page and then '<?php the_content(); ?>
       <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>' in the template I'm using and it doesn't do anything. I don't see any links. If I used the default single page instead of my custom page template which also contains '<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>' that doesn't work either. So I figured it might be missing somewhere deeper.

Comment: As I said, your theme or a plugin could filter the output but I don't know how to guess at that. Are you seeing [errors](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)? Does it work with a bundled theme like Twenty Fourteen?