# importing table data to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-insert-post

i'm trying to import data from table to custom post types below is the code i'm using but this $row['Title'] return nothing ... if i hard code it works

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM Products");

  foreach ($rows as $row) 
      {

      $new_post = wp_insert_post(array(
      'post_type' => 'products', 
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post_author' => $authorID,
      'post_title'  => $row['Title']
      ));

      if( !is_wp_error($new_post) )
        {

          update_post_meta($new_post, "shakamaka", $row['DocFileID']);

        }
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` doesn't look like you think it does. `$wpdb->get_results` will by default return an array of *objects*. Your code-- `'post_title'  => $row['Title']`-- treats an object like an array and should generate a Fatal Error, which you'd see if you had [debugging enabled](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376).

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ...

You need object syntax. Try (using a Core table):

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts");
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  // echo $row['post_author']; // doesn't work
  echo $row->post_author; // works
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot S_HA_DUM, how should i have known this that $wpdb->get_results is returning an array of objects ?

Comment: You could [read the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) to start, or just dump the data and look at it-- `var-dump($rows)`-- both pretty basic development/debugging steps.