# Plugin installation error in wordpress

Tags: plugins, errors

I am trying to install plugin by tgm class, when click on install plugin that is Layer

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in \wp-includes\update.php on line 119
>
> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in \wp-includes\update.php on line 295
>
> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in \wp-includes\update.php on line 457

Please guide me what to do.

Then I tried to install plugin manually on another wordpress, and it generated error

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in \wp-includes\update.php on line 295

Comment: [Enable debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983) and post the results. What is the plugin?

Comment: Can you install other plugins correctly? Are these two WordPress instances on the same server? Which versions are they?