# Wordpress login process is hanging

Tags: admin, login, wp-login-form

I am trying to log in to the admin of my wordpress site that is hosted on my server. Currently when I enter my username and password I do not get an error message, the login process seems to hang on the `wp-login.php` page.

I thought that perhaps it was an issue with my server as the main site loads fine. So I logged in using `SSH` and restarted `Tomcat`.

I then opened the site up again and attempted to login. Unfortunately, the results where the same. The process is continuing to hang when I press login.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? I spoke to the clients who said they logged in successfully last week and had been doing so for a year beforehand as well. I asked had they updated wordpress recentley, to which they responded by saying "No".

So I am at a loss as to the potential cause of this problem. Can anyone advise me on the next best course of action?

Comment: Are you using any authentication plugins?  To debug I would first disable all plugins and check if login works.

Comment: Literally just did that, checked out the plugins in use, there are just two of them `iframe-embed-for-youtube` and `akismet` I renames both folder names and attempted login again. Still not working

Comment: I would disable ALL plugins.  Not sure if you are using mutlsite which sometimes hides Network activated plugins.  I do it by renaming the plugin directory to 'plugins.bak'.  Also you could try switching to a default theme.

Comment: I only have 2 plugins installed...I renamed the directory and still no improvement.

Comment: Did you try switching to a default theme?  My last suggestion is to look at .htaccess   Keep a backup and rename the file to  .htaccess.bak  I dont have any ideas after that  :(

Comment: [Enable debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983) and post the output, if any.