# get_term_link() returns correct - But illogical error-messages disturb

Tags: php, errors, terms, variables

I've a really strange issue with Wordpress and the get_the_link()-function and a following issue with objects who are objects, but identified as non-object-error, itself they are working.

**First the get_term_link() Issue:**

If I ask with a normal number and taxonomy, it works well:

`$tax_name = 'products';
print get_term_link(13, $tax_name);`

It returns the url, but if I do it like following:

`$tax_id = (int)$navItem['id'];
$tax_name = 'products';
print get_term_link($tax_id , $tax_name);`

I got the error-message:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/username/www/domainname/wp-content/themes/theme/sidebar-left.php on line 89

Which last line was 89. ( var_dump of tax_id was *int(13)* )

Without the (int) before the navItem['id] var_dump resulted in *string(2)*.

Tried this with a get_term_by()-function as source, too.

`$term = get_term_by('id', $navItem['id'], $tax_name);
$tax_id = $term->term_id;
var_dump($tax_id);
$tax_name = 'products';
print get_term_link($tax_id , $tax_name);`

Got a new error message as additional :

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/username/www/domainname/wp-content/themes/theme/sidebar-left.php on line 88

What's wrong, because line 88 is in this example "$tax_id = $term->term_id;"! I can use (int) but this don't change the error-message.

The funny thing is, the $term variable is an object. And this error message explains me that I try to get a property from a non-object. If I convert this object to an array (get_object_vars()-function), and access the values in the array like an array (name[key])

I get the following error message:

> get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given line 86

I tried to convert them to integer, then to string. Tried to use slug instead of ID. But nothing worked. The results working!

**Yeah! All showed lines returning the correct link-url!**

But I get this error messages... and I don't understand why. Because... they are totally illogical for me. But I think or more, I hope that I'm the illogical part of this issue and someone can help me to solve/understand this.

And NO... I don't like to turn/hide the error-messages.

Answer (score 1):

`get_term_link()` will [return a `WP_Error` object on error](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link#Return_Values).

You can't `print` an object or array or you will get messages similar to what you are getting. Use `var_dump()` instead or `print_r()` and you should see what is occuring. Your error even tells you that `WP_Error` is the object involved.

You are getting errors when the term you are looking for is not found.

And yes, you should hide your error messages on a production site. They can be revealing. [Write to a log if you must have errors on the production site.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)

Comment: I know that and the contents of the objects/array I everytimes checking by var_dump() and print_ar().

Comment: (Additional comment-text, because of 5 min Edit limit)

To turn debug-modus and error-messages on a production-site, I already know too.

But at the moment the page is on a test-server and there I've the error-messages for development. And what i meant with the last line was, that I don't like the answers/comments who recommending you to hide simply the error messages. (understandable that I will publish later a stable and error-free version of the theme)

Comment: Sorry, if this doesn't answer your question then I don't know what the question is.

Comment: No, you don't have too. The question was, why I got this error-messages, because I don't understood them. Talking from non-object related to an object was to curious. But I solved it now... or more worked around of it. (specify ARRAY_A as output format of the get_terms_by()-function to get a clean array)