# get_post_meta as a list for drop down search filter

Tags: metabox, meta-query, post-meta

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I would like to create a dropdown search filter for my wordpress site. I would like the drop downs to be populated by meta_boxes values which i have for a custom post type. I know that `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_field', true); ?>` is the way to get them but i would like to create a variable and echo it out as a list for a drop down.

```
<select>

    $variable = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_field', true); 

    foreach( $variable  as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo '<option>';

        echo '$variable';

        echo '</option>';
    }
</select>
```

but it does not seem to work, does anyone know why? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You `option` is missing an important part-- the `value=` part. This looks to be a pure HTML question, which will be off-topic here.

Comment: @s_ha_sum I believe this is more than a html question it's a wordpress development question. I am asking how I would create a variable to display a list of the values from the meta key. I would imagine once I have that I could display them in a drop down. Similar logic.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a very basic PHP mistake: [single quotes mean "string literal"](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). Variables won't be processed. You are literally putting "$variable" into the generated code.

Second, look at the third parameter of `get_post_meta()`

> $single   (boolean) (optional)
>   If set to true then the function will
>   return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the
>   function returns an array of the custom fields. This may not be
>   intuitive in the context of serialized arrays. If you fetch a
>   serialized array with this method you want $single to be true to
>   actually get an unserialized array back. If you pass in false, or
>   leave it out, you will have an array of one, and the value at index 0
>   will be the serialized string.
>   Default: false

You are asking for a single variable as a string, and are then trying to iterate over it as if it were an array. I am surprised you aren't getting errors. (see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)

It looks to me like you need to drop that third parameter or set it to `false` (the default), which will return an `array` that you can iterate over.

Comment: I am not receiving errors. The drop down is displayed but the values are not inside the <option></option> I even changed the third parameter to false but no luck.

Comment: See the edit... right at the top. If you are not getting errors, you probably don't have debugging on, hence the link.

Answer (score 1):

This outputs what I need incase anyone is wondering how they would create a drop down from you metakey values.

```
<select>
         <?php  while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

         <option><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Meta_key', true); ?></option>

         <?php
            endwhile;
        ?>
       </select>
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked a treat for me! @steamfunk

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this one-

```
$variable = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_field', true ); // assuming this returns an array

$dropdown = '';
$dropdown .= '<select>';

    if( ! count( $variable ) ){
        $dropdown .= '<option>Not found!</option>';
    }
    else{
        foreach( $variable  as $option ) {
            $dropdown .= '<option>' . $option . '</option>';
        }
    }

$dropdown .= '</select>';

echo $dropdown;
```