# Why does my site often display 404 on subpages?

Tags: posts, 404-error

About once or twice a week, my site will display a 404 page on everything but the home page. The simple fix has been to change the Permalinks settings to "Default" and then back to "Post Name" and it fixes it. While this is a temporary fix, I'd like to know the real issue.  My .htacess file is set to 644. WP and all my plugins are up to date also.

Comment: No idea. Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)? Do you have this problem with all plugins disabled and using a Core-bundled theme like the Twenty-something ones?

Comment: Does your .htaccess disappear or any other plugin messing up your rewrites?

Comment: No. Nothing seems out of ordinary.

Comment: I'll see if I can log the debugging information

Comment: Be sure to check the actual server logs too, including the MySQL one, if you have access.

Comment: Where would the MySQL logs be?

Comment: No errors. Still looking for a solution.