# What is the most efficient way to search users by their display name?

Tags: php, sort, memory, users, wp-user-query

Initially I thought I'd use `get_users()` but it turned out it doesn't support the display_name field. Then I've read about using WP_User_Query, but when I do it always exhausts the allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes. When I remove the memory limit this part of the page doesn't even try to load. Now I'm thinking about running a function that adds everyone's display_name to their user meta so I can use `get_users()` again. Is that a good idea?

My objective is to make the search also sort by relevance and I plan to do it by using `explode(' ', $search_query)` then call `get_users()` for each element in the array, then combine and sort the results by occurance like it's shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176626/php-get-element-with-5-highest-occurrence-in-an-array and I'm not sure if that's going to be memory efficient.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Nope, it doesn't generate any logs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the default class for this job - [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query).
The query have a lot of possibilities, also get the display name. WP_User_Query is a class that allows querying WordPress database tables `_users` and `_usermeta`.

Also it is helpful when you use a cache for the values. Also here I prefer the WordPress defaults `WP_Cache` (Non-Persistent Cache) or transient API (Database-Driven Temporarily Persistent Cache).

The example below will demonstrate this with WP_Cache, you can also doing this with transients. The code will not work, is only write by scratch to illustrate.

```
function wpse_get_user_data( $args ) {


    if ( ! $user_query = wp_cache_get( $args->ID, 'your_key' ) ) {
        $user_query = array();
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

        wp_cache_add( $args-ID, $user_query, 'your_key' );
    }

    return $user_query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but seems like the memory still needs to be used before adding anything to the cache. The moment the line containing `WP_User_Query` starts executing I get a fatal error about exhausting the allowed memory size.

Comment: How much users do you have? But you can reduce the default query,  that you use only the query about one field.

Comment: 1700, is that much? Wouldn't be good if one can't search through all users, but just for testing, how can I do the thing you said?

Comment: No, is much for a lot of installs. But we have a lot of clients, there have much more. The second answer demonstrate the reduction of a smaller search, faster, lower memory.

Comment: Sorry, could you rephrase that? I don't think I understood it at all.

Comment: Add the source of the other answer to your code, that you reduce the query for more performance. - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188888/170

Comment: With the code it tried to allocate tried to allocate 156689661 bytes and without the code it tried to allocate 156689589 bytes. Then I tried two mode times to see that the bytes vary so this probably has no effect at all. I've also mentioned that the page wont load if I give it enough memory.

Comment: But the caching effect is only helpful after loading, at first select of user query is the memory load high. I have no other idea to reduce this via php. Maybe a change on the server is helpful, at first I would play with the values of the php.ini

Comment: editing the ini itself resulted in messages like `Allowed memory size of 168820736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 158593117 bytes)`. Setting the limit to anything higher than 161M resuts in a dialog box about apache not responding.

Answer (score 1):

If you push a "search" through `WP_User_query` you will search both the `user_login` fields and the `user_nicename` fields. That produces a *de facto* inefficient `OR` query. You can reduce that by using a filter to force the search to only the `user_nicename` field.

```
add_filter('user_search_columns','nicename_only_wpse_188846');

function nicename_only_wpse_188846($search_columns) {
  return array('user_nicename');
}

$args = array(
  'search' => 'abce',
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
var_dump($user_query);
```

Combine that with caching and you might have a shot.

That said, `134217728` bytes is pretty slim if you have a lot of users and traffic. You may just need a server upgrade.

Comment: Currently I am still testing that locally, so that's just the limit set in the ini file. Also the page doesn't load not only when I remove the limit, but also when I set the limit to be enough for the current case. I know I have enough space on my C drive.