# Cloning wordpress intsall on mac

Tags: localhost, mac

I'm having a problem with cloning my local website. I'm using a mac OS10.10.3, php 5.5.2 and mysql 5.6.23. Im not using MAMP, just the php bundled inside the mac and I manually installed mysql.

I can install a new wordpress site in the localhost and I can successfully migrate from local to live but when I try to clone a website or migrate a site from live to local screen turns white.. my process for cloning/migrating are as follows:

1. create a new folder called "new-site" inside localhost to store wordpress files
2. copy fresh wordpress inside "new-site"
3. copy plugins, themes, uploads and wp-config from the old-site I'm cloning inside "new-site" and change dbname, dbpass, dbhost
4. create new db for new-site
5. export db from old-site then dump, replace URLs
6. import old-site db to new-site db

Need help

Comment: Welcome to WPSE Baro. Let me start off with a tip: If you want people to put effort in helping you the least to expect is that you read what you've written and check for typos before you press send.

Comment: What are the versions of remote and local WP? Are they the same? Do you change anything in DB (i.e. site_url option)? What do you see when you turn DEBUG on?

Comment: Hi, both wp are versions 4.2.2. Yes, both are the same. And yes I did change the site url from (localhost/~wubu/old-site to localhost/~wubu/new-site). I only see white screen even if DEBUG=true except for one that says "can't select database, your username and password appear to be okay".I've checked that I've entered the correct dbname dbpass dbhost in the wp-config but still error appears but when I tried installing a fresh copy using the same dbname, dbpass etc. it works fine..

Comment: Please provide [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. Here's the error code generated -> 
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '‘root’'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /Users/baro/Sites/outsourced/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1444
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Users/baro/Sites/outsourced/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1474
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user '‘root’'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /Users/baro/Sites/outsourced/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1474

Comment: additional error messages:

Error establishing a database connection
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host's database server is down.

-Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
-Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
-Are you sure that the database server is running?