# Login just resets/reset password link also does not work

Tags: login, reset

All of a sudden I can't log in to a site I've been working on for years.  Made some changes to content yesterday but didn't make any plugin/WP version changes.  A few minutes later went in to make a few more changes. Every time I try to login, it just resets. No error, just a page refresh and blank fields.  Tried this in two browsers, one if which I don't think I had ever logged in with. Same problem.  Tried resetting the password. The link in the reset password form just says "invalid key." I also replaced the wp-login.php file with a fresh copy.  Any other ideas?  The front-end of the site continues to work fine.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information]( http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)?

Comment: speak to your host

Answer (score 0):

Good call.  The host found a tmp directory that wasn't deleting files and was so bloated no more changes could be made.