# My Wordpress Website Has Gone

Tags: support

I have lost my wordpress website.

I tried to edit the Custom CSS. I didn't have a Child Theme as I didn't know what one was until now. I clearly have put the code in the wrong area and it's ruined it. But it has gone blank and I can't access the website I was creating.

I was editing using MAMP as I don't have a server yet. Is there anything I can do?

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: A blank screen usually indicates a fatal error occurred, but your server has been configured to not display the errors. It may have been sent to an error log, or you may need to adjust MAMPs settings. Then you'll be able to see what the actual problem is

Comment: You could try to empty the custom css accessing the db with a mysql client, inside the table wp_options... this if you actually edited that form/field.

Answer (score 1):

> I was editing using MAMP as I don't have a server yet.

MAMP is a server-- well, server package. The "A" stands for "Apache", as in "Apache web server".

> Is there anything I can do?

Edit the files with a real code editor instead of that travesty of an editor built into WordPress. On a Mac, Textwrangler is solid as is its big brother BBedit. Jedit is pretty good too.

Grab an editor and brows to your server's web root. I don't remember the defaults for MAMP but it ought to have a help file. Edit away.

[You will need to configure your server to show errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581460/why-mamp-doesnt-display-errors) Also, you probably want to [turn on WordPress' debugging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376) while you work. With that done, you should see messages telling you the file name and the line number of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Some Times, remove the your theme forcely.

login to shell,

```
cd [web server root]/wordpress/wp-content/themes
```

and,

```
rm -rf [your theme name]
```

or

```
mv [your theme name] [your theme name].notgood
```

or move to another location

```
mv [your theme name] ../../../
```

then,
access your website admin then default theme will be used. and you can see admin dashboard.

and correct again.

good job.