# Weird Behaviour: Not all Wordpress Posts appearing

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, functions, database

My wordpress posts have vanished on my dashboard but remain in the database? Meaning I have many 404 errors.

All (52) | Published (4) | Drafts (7) | Trash (2) TOTAL =11 items

(Note how theres only 11 items should be way more)

What I have done:

1) I restored my website to a week ago, but the posts are still not appearing.

I believe it's an environment issue? What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: And you have disabled all of your plugins and switched to a bundled theme (Twenty Something )?

Comment: Yes I tired that and didn't work

Comment: I don't know how to guess at the cause. Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)?

Comment: I tired that also :/

Comment: So your question is "given zero information, what do you think is wrong?" I don't know how to answer that. Sorry.

Comment: There's nothing in the logs, that suggests there's an issue.

Comment: Are you using a plugin which expires posts and/or are your posts published / unpublished on a schedule? If so, maybe check the date/time on your server?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer with not much information, but here are some things you can try and ask yourself:

- Reset your permalinks (Settings > Permalinks > Save Changes)
- What happens when you set WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php file?
- Is this a custom post type, or was anything recently changed that may have caused this?

Comment: Hi, custom post types are heavily affected, also page posts. Nothing major changed in code, plugins were deactivated also no issues there..changing themes doesn't help.  I tried all of the above steps. I did notice something odd in the database.

I see in my custom posts table theres two enters for each custom post.

X - Has a date Jan14th- 2:06pm - post_status: expired

Y - Has a date Jan14th- 2:05pm - post_status: inherit.

Would that be my issue? That posts like X are seen as expired?

Comment: Just to note there's nothing of interest in the  WP_DEBUG. 2 days on this issue :/ total pain. thanks for helping