# get_home_path() returning error 500

Tags: homepage, 500-internal-error

I'm using `get_home_path()` because i need to store a file from a temporary directory to an archive folder (i'm doing this using php's `copy()` function).

The problem is that `get_home_path()` returns me an error 500 (internal server error). If i comment that function, the script works.

Any idea on why is this happening?

**UPDATE as per s_ha_dum's request**

here's the debug log:

> [09-Jul-2015 07:36:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined
>   function get_home_path() in
>   /www/ggp.com/wp-content/themes/ggp/functions.php on line 649

**UPDATE: my code**

```
function save_sent_mail_function() {

    [...]

        $home_path = get_home_path();

        $cvs_path = '/wp-content/uploads/cvs/'.$file_name;

        copy($file['cv'], $home_path.$cvs_path);

    [...]

}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'save_sent_mail_function');
```

I found out that there's the `ABSPATH` constant that i can use instead of the `$home_path` variable

Comment: Interesting. That is a pretty simple function. Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)? Do you have access to the server logs? Post your code please.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i've updated the question with the debug log

Comment: @s_ha_dum problem is that `wp-admin/includes/file.php` is not being included because if i copy `get_home_path()` in my `functions.php` it works correctly

Comment: So you are using a backend function on the front end. ***Post your code please.***

Comment: @s_ha_dum and where exactly in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) is mentioned that this is a backend function only?

Comment: I am trying in backend and similarly getting 500 error :(