# Shortcode At top of Page - PHP 5.5 vs 5.4 - ob_start();

Tags: php, shortcode

```
add_shortcode( 'recent-events', 'recent_events' );
function recent_events( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
            'count' => '2',
            'columns' => '1'
        ), $atts);

    //Column Setup
    $columns = (12/$atts['columns']);

    $amount = $atts['count'];
    $nmonth = intval(date("m"));
    $month_hold = '';
    $date = new DateTime();
    $todaysDate = date('d.M.y');
    $todaysString = strtotime($todaysDate);
    $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'event', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order'     => 'ASC',
                'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
                'meta_key'  => '_start_eventtimestamp',
                'meta_query'     => array(
                    array(
                      'key'     => '_start_eventtimestamp',
                      'value'   => '1434476216',
                      'compare' => '>'
                    ) 
                  )
            );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
            $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());

        //print_r($meta);
        $month_hold_1 = $meta['_start_month'][0];
        if($nmonth > intval($month_hold_1)){
            $str = get_the_title();
            echo '<script>console.log("Old Event: '.$str.'");</script>';
            //the_title();
        } else {
            if($counter >= $amount){
                return false;
            } else {
                $counter ++;
            }
            if($month_hold !== $month_hold_1){
                $months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                $hourConvert = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];
                //echo '<div class="event-month-title"><h2>'.$months[intval($month_hold_1) - 1]. ' '. $meta['_start_year'][0].'</h2></div>';
                if(intval($meta['_start_hour'][0]) < 12){
                    $time_start = 'am';
                } else {
                    $time_start = 'pm';
                }
                if(intval($meta['_end_hour'][0]) < 12){
                    $time_end = 'am';
                } else {
                    $time_end = 'pm';
                }
            }


            echo '<ul class="event-container event-list clearfix columns medium-'.$columns.'">';
            ?>
                  <li class="event-date-container">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="event-date-wrapper">
                        <div class="event-date-holder">
                          <span class="event-date"><?php echo $meta['_start_day'][0]; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="event-date-month-year"><?php echo $months[intval($month_hold_1) - 1].' '.$meta['_start_year'][0]; ?> </div>
                      </div>
                    </a> 
                  </li>
                  <li class="event-description-container">
                    <div class="event-description">
                      <h5 class="event-title">
                        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a>' ); ?>
                      </h5>
                      <?php 
                          echo '<p class="event-metadata">'.$months[intval($month_hold_1) - 1].' '.$meta['_start_day'][0];
                          if($meta['_start_day'][0] != $meta['_end_day'][0]){
                            echo ' - '.$months[intval($month_hold_1) - 1].' '.$meta['_end_day'][0];//.' @ '.$hourConvert[intval($meta['_start_hour'][0])].':'.$meta['_start_minute'][0].$time_start.' - '.$hourConvert[intval($meta['_end_hour'][0])].':'.$meta['_end_minute'][0].$time_end.'</p>';
                          } else {
                            //echo ' @ '.$hourConvert[intval($meta['_start_hour'][0])].':'.$meta['_start_minute'][0].$time_start.' - '.$hourConvert[intval($meta['_end_hour'][0])].':'.$meta['_end_minute'][0].$time_end.'</p>';
                          }
                      ?>
                      <p class="event-metadata">
                        <span class="event-location">
                          <strong><?php echo $meta['_event_location'][0]; ?></strong>
                        </span>
                       <!--  • 
                        <span class="event-cost">
                          <strong>Free</strong>
                        </span>  -->           
                      </p>
                      <div class="event-description copy">
                        <p>
                          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </p>
                        <?php echo '<p> <a class="linked-text" href="'.$meta['_event_register'][0].'">Register</a> • <a class="primary" href="'.esc_url( get_permalink()).'" rel="bookmark">Learn More</a></p>'; ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </li>
            </ul>
<?php  }
        endwhile;
        $month_hold = $month_hold_1;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
        return $myvariable;
}
```

Here is my shortcode - it works fine on my local, which runs PHP 5.4 vs php 5.5 on my actual server, i'm not sure if that's it though, on the page it is placed, it doesn't work, but it works on some other pages.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, can you be more descriptive? How does it not work? What are you expecting, and what are you getting instead? Unrelated, your code contains numerous injection attack vulnerabilities, consider escaping your output

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983?s=1|3.2035#95983)?

Comment: The code will work on some pages, playing the shortcode return in the correct place on the page, but there is a specific page it will not work on, which would make you think it's just that page, but I can copy that page to another identical installation on a different server running php 5.4 and it will not work. I went through over 50 different forum posts of similar issue, but none of them gave me the answer. All I had already tried or implemented.