# PHP Shortcode - 500 error

Tags: php, shortcode, 500-internal-error

I have been working on a shortcode with help from this article: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-shortcode-to-list-posts-with-multiple-parameters--wp-32199. 
I have tried to do what the article says, however I have tried to include a while loop. The problem is that when I paste it into the functions.php in the theme editor, the page crashes and returns internal server error 500.

My code looks like this:

```
add_shortcode('lande_galleri', 'lande_galleri_parameter');

function lande_galleri_parameter($atts) {
ob_start();

//Definer attributter
extract( shortcode_atts( array (
    'post_type' => 'embm_beer',
    'order' =>'date',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts' => -1,
    'land' => '',
), $atts));

//Definer parametre
$options = array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'order' => $order,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts,
    'land' => $land,
);
$query = new WP_Query($options);

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();{ ?>
    <div class="findoel"> <?php
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" title="' . esc_attr($post->post_title) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'medium');
        echo '</a>';?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();

$myvariable = ob_get_clean();
return $myvariable;
}
}
```

Can anyone see the problem?

The point of the shortcode: I have a custom post type with a taxanomy. I would like to have the shortcode attribute "land", and then if the input is for example "germany", I would like the file to get all of the posts within the category, and they display the post thumbnails.

Comment: Look at the end of the `if ($query->have_posts())` line. What is that `{` doing there?

Comment: If you had [debugging enabled](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376) you would have spotted that.

Comment: I tried removing the {, but it still makes the server error

Comment: did you also remove the extra closing } at the bottom? have you enabled debugging yet? ;)

Comment: You are also missing an `endif`. If you would indent carefully and avoid those nightmarish "template tag" style conditionals you'd spot this this stuff much more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @s_ha_dum said, those nightmarish "template tag" style conditionals made it hard to find those errors. Please use `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your wp-config file to print those PHP errors while you are developing.

```
function lande_galleri_parameter($atts) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'post_type' => 'embm_beer',
        'order' =>'date',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts' => -1,
        'land' => '',
    ), $atts));

    $options = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'order' => $order,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'land' => $land,
    );

    $out = '';

    $query = new WP_Query($options);

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $out .= '<div class="findoel"><a href="' . get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
            $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'medium');
            $out .= '</a></div>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $$out;
}
add_shortcode('lande_galleri', 'lande_galleri_parameter');
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. And from now on, I will use the DEBUG