# My footer has disappeared but only on my home page

Tags: footer

I've recently put up a clients website and all was fine, however a few days later I'm returning to finish a few things up and the footer is gone from the homepage! It's showing on all other pages, just not the homepage. I've tested it out by deactivate all 13 plugins and the doing a hard refresh but it didn't seem to update or change anything. I've checked the source code as well but can't seem to find anything other than the my #footer has been completely removed.. [Here is my site](http://benchmarkdata.ca) for reference.

If anyone could shed some light on as to what may be happening I would be greatly appreciative!

UPDATE:

After adding this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

to my theme I've got the debug.log up it's referencing this line

```
[18-Nov-2015 01:53:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function the_excerpt_reloaded() in /services/webpages/b/e/benchmarkdata.ca/public/wp-content/themes/BenchMark/index.php on line 69
[18-Nov-2015 01:53:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function the_excerpt_reloaded() in /services/webpages/b/e/benchmarkdata.ca/public/wp-content/themes/BenchMark/index.php on line 69
```

but I've never heard of it before. Does this error look familiar to anyone?

Comment: You have a fatal PHP error, [Turn on debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)

Comment: @s_ha_dum is correct, this normally happens if something before the footer crashes, usually something in a widget or sidebar. Sidebars and widgets are good starting points here

Comment: Thanks guys for that suggestion. I've since updated my question as now it's pointing me in a direction but I still don't understand what the error means. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `the_excerpt_reloaded()` is a function that does not exist. Trying to call a function that does not exist leads to such fatal errors

Comment: Through everyones help I was able to hunt it down. Thanks guys! I posted an answer for future issues people may run into.

Answer (score 0):

So what ended up happenign was I was working with an older hand made theme and the main wordpress hadn't been updated in a while. After updating the

```
<php the_excerpt_reloaded(35, '<p><b><i><u><em><strong><blockquote><a><ol><ul><li>', 'content', TRUE, 0); ?>
```

they had in the index.php file was obsolutelt as Pieter Goosen stated. I then had to find out how I was supposed to update this snippet with a new code. In comes

```
<?php the_excerpt() ?>
```

So what I've learned from this first experience of really looking for the issues is ALWAYS set your debug to true and go to the file and line it states, then play with some different alternatives and of course it's always nice to have help! Thanks guys! Google. Google helps too.