# White blank page when Updating/Draft/Publishing Page/Post

Tags: multisite, plugin-w3-total-cache, fatal-error, google-chrome

On my VPS (**centos 6.7 64x, 2 cpu's and 3gb ram**) I have setup a WP MU(Memory usage: 53.97 MByte)and many times I have a blank page when I make a post draft or publish/updating it, or when I want to move as an admin to another option in wp.

I have added on the top of the file wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

Also, by doing 'inspect element on chrome, I noticed that it shows me this this error:

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH**

I enable the debugging

```
// Turn debugging on
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Tell WordPress to log everything to /wp-content/debug.log
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Turn off the display of error messages on your site
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

// For good measure, you can also add the follow code, which will hide errors from being displayed on-screen
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

I decided to make a new post and save it as a draft. It showed me a blank white page while it was saving it. And I got this on debug.log

```
[22-Nov-2015 21:37:02 UTC] 
--------------------------------------
REQUEST: /wp-admin/post.php


[22-Nov-2015 21:37:04 UTC] 
--------------------------------------
REQUEST: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php


[22-Nov-2015 21:37:04 UTC] 
--------------------------------------
REQUEST: /wp-admin/post.php?post=34890&action=edit&message=10


[22-Nov-2015 21:37:10 UTC] 
--------------------------------------
REQUEST: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php


[22-Nov-2015 21:39:04 UTC] 
--------------------------------------
REQUEST: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

I never had this problem before (I use the same theme/plugins) I upgrade (centos from 5.5 to 6.7 64bit)the os of the server(I don't if this has something to do with the problem). I use the same theme/plugins.

**Update**
I increased apache/php limits by adding the following 2 lines in /etc/httpd/apache/conf/php.conf

FcgidIOTimeout 400

MaxRequestLen 20468982

```
# This file was automatically generated by the Cpanel PHP Configuration system
# If you wish to change the way PHP is being handled by Apache on your system,
# use the /usr/local/cpanel/bin/rebuild_phpconf script or the WHM interface.
#
# Manual edits of this file will be lost when Apache is updated.


# Fastcgi configuration for PHP5
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
MaxRequestsPerProcess 500
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php5
FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php4
FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php
FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php3
FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php2
FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .phtml

# End of autogenerated PHP configuration.
FcgidIOTimeout 400
MaxRequestLen 20468982
```

Before, every time I were publishing/update or draft a post it was showing the problem on every thing. Now, the problem is random since I increased the apache/php limits. Does it mean that something else (how can I find it?) is putting load on vps or do I have to increase more the apache/php?

I have added w3tc plugin and optimised the sites but it didn't change anything. Should I add apcu or memcache / memcached combined with varnish or more RAM?

P.S.:[This is my.cnf](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121810/optimise-mysql-on-vps-2-cpus-3-gb-ram-with-wp-mu) in the case that is needed as extra info to fix the problem that I have.

Comment: Well... https://www.google.com/search?q=net%3A%3AERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Comment: @s_ha_dum I searched with these keywords "White blank page wordpress net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" and I din't find anything that helped me. So I post it here..

Comment: You post no code. You post, at best, a truncated error message. You don't mention theme, plugins, or what you've already tried. You probably don't have [debugging enabled](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376). And you want someone to guess what the problem is and solve it for you?

Comment: Post updated. I hope now its ok for someone to help me :)

Comment: Did you do the update or did you host do it?

Comment: my host, that is why I didn't mention these details on the start

Answer (score 1):

```
There will be many reasons for blank page, you have not mention version for wp, php etc.
**To solve wordpress blank page issue follow the steps**
```

1. disable all plugin and try (if there is an error in plugins then enable 1 by 1)
2. switch to default theme and try (if there is an error in theme)
3. rename .htaccess and param-link to default (page/post id)