# Child theme Page Template not loading

Tags: themes, templates

I've currently setup a multilingual multisite. But one page isn't picking up the parents page template.

Working:
http://www.jeroenbrugman.com/contact

Not working:
http://www.jeroenbrugman.com/en/contact

All the other pages are setup up the exact same way, and they do use the parents page template. However, the contact page doesn't....

Comment: Can you provide some background as to how you've implemented this? Are you using a multilingual plugin? If so which one? Pages don't inherit page templates, if you're expecting all subpages to have the same template when you set a pages template, then you're mistaken

Comment: I setup a multisite using wordpress's built in part .com is my main site (dutch) and .com/en/ is my subsite (english). I used NSCloner to clone all pages to the subsite. And everything worked immediately except for the contact page.

Comment: If that is the only page not working can't you manually set the template?

Comment: I can only set the templates on my main themes pages. Non of my child theme pages. Also. When you change the language from dutch to english and you refresh on home. The page turns blank?

Comment: @s_ha_dum See my comment above

Comment: Are the `en/*` pages child pages? You called that a "subsite". The blank page indicates a fatal error. [Turn on debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983?s=1|3.2104#95983). That should help.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like something weird with that plugin which may make this question off-topic but please at least add debugging information ([edit] it into the question rather than as a comment)

Comment: @s_ha_dum This is what I found so far. Seem a lot of errors.. http://textuploader.com/5h96f

Comment: Yes. Lots of fatal errors. Have you hacked the theme?

Comment: No not at all.   Are there any errors related to the contact page?

Comment: @s_ha_dum i do see some fatal errors in my functions.php

Comment: NSCloner plugin appears to copy sites not pages

Comment: @TomJNowell Also the pages. Because the pages used to work perfectly.

Comment: They aren't the same pages, they're copies, if the copies of the pages do not work after the copying, you should clarify that, if on the other hand they worked after copying, and then at some unspecified time afterwards they stopped working, that's important information. I **strongly** recommend you fix the fatal errors you found, until they're fixed there's nothing more that can be done, in the same way that you can't build a penthouse if you've not built foundations

Comment: @TomJNowell I checked all the fatal errors. But no one to be found. All the unexpected < are not there. No < too much or too less.. And this implies for all the errors. Very strange

Comment: @TomJNowell I did found something! On my english site. In Appearance > Themes it says ERROR: Template is missing. Maybe this could help?

Comment: @TomJNowell I FOUND THE SOLUTION! I uploaded header.php footer.php and page.php to my child theme folder. This made the admin show page template selection menu

Comment: Great, add that as an answer, along with an explanation of why the problem happened so others can learn, and you can get upvotes for bounties on future questions :)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by adding my parent's index,page, and header.php to my child theme's folder.

If you're not able to change the blog page template. Remove the page from the Settings > Reading, change the template and select your blog post again.