# `update_post_meta` not working anymore

Tags: php, custom-field

Originally my goal was to compress my code, now after I altered it, it is not working anymore. I can't figure out why. I simplified it a bit, now this code should save one date entered in the backend in a custom meta box of a custom post type but apparently the `update_post_meta()` function is not working anymore. E.g. if I select a date and save the post, the change isn't saving.

```
add_action ('admin_init', 'cpt_event_meta_fields');
add_action ('save_post', 'cpt_event_save_data');
    function cpt_event_meta_fields() {
        add_meta_box("event-meta-1", "Datum (von)", "cpt_event_callback", "Termin", "normal", "high");
    }
    function cpt_event_callback( $post ) {
        $dateStart = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date-start', true );
        echo $dateStart;
        echo '<input type="date" name="date-start" value="' . $dateStart . '" />';
    }
    function cpt_event_save_data() {
        global $post;
        update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "date-start", $dateStart);
    }
```

After reviewing the answer below is myupdated code. My main problem was the use of `global $post`outside of the Loop. I used `global $_POST` instead. Also I now changed the input from `date` to `text` and sanitized the textfields using `sanitize_text_field()`

```
add_action ('admin_init', 'cpt_event_meta_fields');
add_action ('save_post', 'cpt_event_save_data');
function cpt_event_meta_fields() {
    add_meta_box("event-meta-1", "Datum (von)", "cpt_event_callback", "Termin", "normal", "high");
    add_meta_box("event-meta-2", "Datum (bis)", "cpt_event_2_callback", "Termin", "normal", "high");
}
function cpt_event_callback( $post ) {
    $dateStart = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date-start', true );
    echo '<input type="text" name="date-start" value="' . $dateStart . '" />';
}
function cpt_event_2_callback( $post ) {
    $dateEnd = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date-end', true );
    echo '<input type="text" name="date-end" value="' . $dateEnd . '" />';
}
function cpt_event_save_data() {
    global $_POST;
    global $dateStart;
    $dateStart = sanitize_text_field($_POST['date-start']);
    $dateEnd = sanitize_text_field($_POST['date-end']);
    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "date-start", $dateStart);
    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "date-end", $dateEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_the_ID()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) is a "Loop" function. It won't outside [the Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), and there is not Loop in your code. Essentially, you are passing a bad `ID` to the function causing it to fail. If you had [debugging enabled](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376) you might see feedback to that effect.

You are also using a variable-- `$dateStart`-- that is not set in the context of the function.

You are not properly using the [`save_post` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post), however. WordPress will pass the post ID through to your callback if you ask for it.

Finally, what you want is `global $_POST;` which is the PHP form data, and not `global $post;` with is a WordPress variable that is a primary component of Loops.

```
function cpt_event_save_data($pid) {
    global $_POST;
    $dateStart = $_POST['date-start']; 
    // sanitize $datestart, maybe with PHP's checkdate()
    // I don't know what the format of your string is though
    update_post_meta($pid, "date-start", $dateStart);
}
```

Untested, but that should be pretty close.

Comment: thank you, the code works flawless. I have debugging enabled but wasn't able to see any feedback in this case. How am I not using save_post correctly? I Wasn't able to sanitize the date yet, it is selected in the standard formattin "dd.mm.jjjj" - How would you approach this? Coudn't get it done with `checkdate` and I am confused by all the possible ways to sanitize PHP

Comment: "How am I not using save_post correctly?" -- I explained that. You are not requesting the post ID via the hook but were trying to use `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: Is your date reliably in that format? Your form doesn't actually seem to enforce any format at all.

Comment: Do I have to enforce a format? In the backend there is a date picker working just the way I want. I Didn't output the meta data to the frontend yet though

Comment: JavaScript can be bypassed but it is probably adequate in this case, with proper sanitization.

Comment: I updated the code. It's working perfeclty now. Would you consider this secure regarding security now?