# Wordpress giving error when I log in after trying emergency.php

Tags: login, internal-server-error

I could not remember my username or password for my WordPress website. I tried using the `emergency.php` script.

I logged and I tried a few different possibilities for username, of which none worked.  Now when I try log in to my website it just has 'error' instead of my site which was working perfectly.

How do I get my site back up and running and is it possible to create new log in details if all I have is the ftp details, thanks.

Comment: If you have access to the database you can manually edit the `wp_users` table where your admin user resides. This may restore access.

Comment: You probably made an error in the emergency script. Post that code (with a fake user and pass) and add [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983?s=1|3.2154#95983)